# RegistryKey Key.GetValue("keyName") is returning wrong values in Unit Test c# project

Tags: c#, unit-testing, registry, msdtc, registrykey

I have this code:

```
RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\MSDTC\\Security");
if (key != null)
{
      Object o = key.GetValue("NetworkDtcAccessInbound");
      if (o != null)
      {
      }
}
```

It returns the **correct value (1)** when i use in normal project, but in Unit Test project it returns **wrong value (0)**, i know coz i see in regedit.

If i check for these keys: **LuTransactions**, **XaTransactions**, it returns correct, even in **Unit Test Project**.

If i check for these: **NetworkDtcAccessInbound**, **NetworkDtcAccessOutbound**, **NetworkDtcAccess** it returns wrong **just in Unit Test Project**

anyone knows about this behavior?

Comment: Likely x86/x64 mismatch (test usually run x86) and hitting different registry branches as result. Side note: usually you don't want to do registry access in unit test (as well as any other external access like DB, file IO)...

Comment: you're right, i found 2 other codes to access the Key, one for RegistryView.Registry32, and another for RegistryView.Registry64, the second returns the correct value, Thanks ^^

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @AlexeiLevenkov said it was a x86/x64 mismatch, the Unit Test runs as x86, but my system is x64,  i did a web search for a code that read registry for each operation system type.

The code below is for x86 operation system, but my computer is x64, so the code below returned a wrong value (value = 0).

```
string value32 = string.Empty;
RegistryKey localKey32 = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry32);
localKey32 = localKey32.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\MSDTC\\Security");
if (localKey32 != null)
{
    value32 = localKey32.GetValue("NetworkDtcAccessInbound").ToString();
}
```

The code below is for x64 operation system, my computer is x64, so the code below returned a correct value (value = 1).

```
string value64 = string.Empty;
RegistryKey localKey = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(Microsoft.Win32.RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64);
localKey = localKey.OpenSubKey("Software\\Microsoft\\MSDTC\\Security");
if (localKey != null)
{
    value64 = localKey.GetValue("NetworkDtcAccessInbound").ToString();
}
```

thats all folks.